# Parsing AT commands & responses in a circular buffer

Tags: c, at-command, circular-buffer

I have a PIC32MM connected via UART with BT module RN4020 and currently struggling with it's configuration. It uses AT-command format **COMMAND+CR+LF** (or **corresponsive ANSWER+CR+LF**).

First, the module is set via special signal line into Command Mode, which after boot-up gives **"CMD\r\n"** on MCU's RX line. I am using default nifty functions provided by MPLAB IDE, which are based on **circular buffers** filled byte by byte during **RX interrupt routine** and I think I've already grasped the simple principle of how they work.

There even is a neat function `ReadBuffer(target string, num of bytes to read)` provided, which reads given amount of bytes from the rx circ buff into a given char array (buffer, string) to work with then.

***My question is*** - what might be the best way to **wait for and recognize a correct answer** and then after it came and is checked, which means the module is ready for a command to be send via TX line, send a command. I need to signalize the moment when the answer from the module is fully read in MCU - in other words, **when to call the ReadBuffer function** so it gives me correct string back and I can be sure that I call *ReadBuffer(my_target_string, 5)* and *my_target_string contains "CMD\r\n"*. I don't want to move the Head&Tail pointers unnecessarily wrongly, and mess up the structure. Is some kind of **timeout** a good way to proceed or is it even better to create some indicator **flag and (un)set it** when CR and LF come?

Thanks for any ideas or hints in advance.

After finding out, that the answer's home, some sort of string compare might be enough to check if it is what is expected I think. (Tricky might be '\0' character, but I'll try to keep that one in mind.)